# Chef recipe order execution

Tags: chef-infra

I have the following code:

```
include_recipe 'hashicorp-vault::default'
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://127.0.0.1:8200')

res = conn.put do |req|
  req.url '/v1/sys/init'
  req.body = '{"secret_shares": 1, "secret_threshold": 1}'
end
```

The problem is that chef ignores `include_recipe 'hashicorp-vault::default'` and executes first the other code, so it crashes because vault is not installed.

How can I force to execute `hashicorp-vault::default` in first place?

Comment: You problem is executing the rest of the code at converge time instead of compile time, see https://coderanger.net/two-pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your code to converge time so the resources defined in the vault recipe have been converged and not just defined:

```
include_recipe 'hashicorp-vault::default'

ruby_block 'get secret' do
  block do
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://127.0.0.1:8200')
    node.run_state['res'] = conn.put do |req|
      req.url '/v1/sys/init'
      req.body = '{"secret_shares": 1, "secret_threshold": 1}'
    end
  end
end
```

And in the rest of the recipe (or other later recipes) where you want to get this secret use `node.run_state['rest']` this specific hash is not saved as part of the node object and as such will not leak the secret into the chef-server.

This behavior is due to the way chef compile recipes and then converge the resources within it, you can find more details on [coderanger's blog](https://coderanger.net/two-pass)